# mod_wsgi asks for Visual c++14.0 but already installed

Tags: python, windows, apache, pip, mod-wsgi

Im trying to install mod_wsgi in Windows 8.1 by using **pip install mod_wsgi** and output that Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required but I already installed it. I all, python, apache and Visual C++ in 64 bit and as mentiond before the library installed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LutzG.jpg)

Some help please...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any Visual C++, you only have Redistributable packages. They install run-time libraries that are used to run applications written with VC. But you need Visual C++ compiler! Install [Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).